# How make such interactive clicable map with marks?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, interactive

Could you please tell me how make such clickable map? Is it possible to make it using mysql and store the point in the database. My knowledge about this issue is very poor so any tutorial or some links to articles where I can read more about this will be very appreciated.

http://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?submit_type=refine&search_form=map&tag=qs&search_type=SS&keyword_value=Postcode%2C+street+or+area&price_from=&price_to=&bedrooms=0&bedrooms_max=&prop_type=&sold=1

http://www.ralf-wessels.de/Beispiele/Bundesland_Bezirk_Kreise.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for your question I think [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch) goes step-by-step from database to map.

I followed mainly the Google tutorials and found them easy to follow. If you're totally new, [start here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) (API key is optional unless you wish to increase certain quotas)

While writing code, you will almost certainly want to look at [the reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

To place [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers) and add [event listeners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventListeners) (like click)

I gathered many other links in [this page](http://exploregooglemaps.blogspot.com.br/p/resources.html)